# How to debug jenkins exception: org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.ExecutorServiceUtils$FatalRejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, jenkins

In jenkins system log, I see a huge number of exception like the following one (~1 per second)

`Jan 06, 2023 4:15:24 PM SEVERE com.google.common.util.concurrent.AggregateFuture log

Got more than one input Future failure. Logging failures after the first
org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.ExecutorServiceUtils$FatalRejectedExecutionException: Cannot execute the command java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1f48e80f. The executor service is shutting down
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService.execute(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:116)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.InterceptingExecutorService.submit(InterceptingExecutorService.java:46)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$5.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:925)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$5.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:921)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.concurrent.Futures$1.run(Futures.java:147)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:33)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1270)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:761)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:136)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:157)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:97)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.runInCpsVmThread(CpsFlowExecution.java:921)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.getCurrentExecutions(CpsFlowExecution.java:1012)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList$StepExecutionIteratorImpl.apply(FlowExecutionList.java:215)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepExecution.applyAll(StepExecution.java:179)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepExecution.applyAll(StepExecution.java:187)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.WaitForConditionStep$Execution.retry(WaitForConditionStep.java:121)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.WaitForConditionStep$Execution.access$000(WaitForConditionStep.java:70)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.WaitForConditionStep$Callback.onSuccess(WaitForConditionStep.java:181)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter.receive(CpsBodyExecution.java:372)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:158)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:152)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)`

Looking at the call stack, I've no idea where it comes from.
How can I debug that ?